# ubuntu-core as container os in base image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I'm currently reviewing possible solutions for container operation systems for our applications. I'm considering RancherOS and Ubuntu-Core. But since we are using docker base images, I'm a little confused how to create a docker base image with ubuntu-core. I can't find an official release candidate from canonical and I don't want to create it myself from a tag. How could I compose the base image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't find an official release candidate from canonical

Yes, there is no officaial image on dockerhub, but [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/multiarch/ubuntu-core) & some other [high pull images](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=ubuntu-core&type=image) are good to use I think.

> How could I compose the base image

If you still do not want to use the images on docker hub. Then in fact you still can form your own docker image based on official `ubuntu-core` release like next:

1. Download Ubuntu Core based on 14.04 version

   ```
   wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/trusty/daily/current/trusty-core-ppc64el.tar.gz
   ```
2. Import the files into docker

   ```
   # cat trusty-core-ppc64el.tar.gz | docker import - ubuntucore
   3ad6c6616b921b10a414238a226fb39eef85d8249ac7d767e84e275aaf90ab65
   ```
3. Guarantee that the image was created:

   ```
   # docker images
   ```
4. Assure that your image is running fine:

   ```
   # docker run ubuntucore ls
   ```

Detail refers to [IBM guide](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/fe313521-2e95-46f2-817d-44a4f27eba32/entry/ubuntu_core_on_docker_for_power?lang=en), and, if you need to use the new version, you also can find it in http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core